# Google Maps for EE, not showing all entries?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-for-ee

I have Google Maps for EE installed, and I am using it to display a full page map with all my entries on. (Currently at about 150 entries).

However at least the first 50 of these entries are not showing.
Each entry has an individual marker that displays correctly on its own single page view, but its completely missing from the full map view view.

Heres my code that I am using to display the full map.

```
<div id="map-holder-main">

    {exp:gmap:init id="map2" scrollwheel="false" style="width:100%;height:100%"}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="walks" disable="member_data|pagination"}

        {exp:gmap:marker id="map2" latitude="{latitude}" longitude="{longitude}" geocode="false" clustering="false" show_one_window="true" maxWidth="200"}

            {lv_walkdetails_map}

        {/exp:gmap:marker}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

</div>
```

Any idea as to why these first 50 or so entries in the channel are not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exp:channel:entries` tag has a default of `limit="100"` so you need to override that with `limit="300"` or a number large enough to accomplish what you need to do.

Comment: Well I never knew that! Many thanks, that has indeed sorted it! :)

Comment: That's one to file away in memory for sure.